# what is making this php code functioning that is outputing HTML?

Tags: php

I'm trying to output a button using PHP but I cant seem to get the `'` and `"` correctly.

This is the output I should be getting from the PHP code below:

```
<button class="button button1" onclick="buttonTest(99.16918,-82.9191)"> Lithuania </button>
```

This is my code:

```
foreach ($getClasses as $row){
echo '<button class="button button1" onclick="buttonTest(', $row->BUILDING_Latitude ,',',$row->BUILDING_Longtitude,)>', $row->COURSE_Title,'</button>';
}
```

how do i get php to output this html code above i get an error

```
syntax error, unexpected '>' (48) : eval()'d code

syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting ',' or ';' (48) : eval()'d code
```

**Update**

Also, please advice me the best way to rewrite this, so that these kind of issues do not occur in the future.

Comment: You missed a `'` here: `tude,')>', $ro`

Comment: "This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error" and should be deleted. It will not be of use to future visitors.

Comment: @miken32 if you look at the edited answer he gave a cleaner solution to this problem although it is a simple error!

Comment: @miken32 Yes, true. At the same time, lemme edit the question to make it not just a typo question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed the `'` here:

```
tude, ')">', $ro
//----^-^
```

Full code:

```
echo '<button class="button button1" onclick="buttonTest(', $row->BUILDING_Latitude ,',',$row->BUILDING_Longtitude, ')">', $row->COURSE_Title,'</button>';
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------^-^
```

I would really write this way:

```
<?php
    foreach ($getClasses as $row) {
        echo "<button class=\"button button1\" onclick=\"buttonTest({$row->BUILDING_Latitude}, {$row->BUILDING_Longtitude})\">{$row->COURSE_Title}</button>";
    }
```

Or even better:

```
<?php
    foreach ($getClasses as $row) {
        $lat = $row->BUILDING_Latitude;
        $lon = $row->BUILDING_Longtitude;
        $course = $row->COURSE_Title;
        echo "<button class=\"button button1\" onclick=\"buttonTest($lat, $lon)\">$course</button>";
    }
```

Comment: thank you very much ive been staring at the same piece of code for hours could not figure it out!